# Discrepancy between Minimize and NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I was trying to minimize a quartic polyonomial equation with a constraint using Mathematica but I got some conflicting results and I wanted to ask to you. Am I making a conceptual mistake or a coding mistake?

First I wanted to minimize using the Minimize function:

```
Minimize[pol1[1.9, 0.1], 
  c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 == 1, {c0r, c0i, c1r, c1i}];
```

As you can see the function called pol1 and the constraint is a unit sphere. Function is a quartic polynomial with funny coefficients:

```
 Chop[N[pol1[1.9, 0.1]]]
2.23232 c0i^2 - 0.0995481 c0i^4 + 2.23232 c0r^2 - 
 0.199096 c0i^2 c0r^2 - 0.0995481 c0r^4 - 0.433493 c0i c1i + 
 0.126205 c0i^3 c1i + 2.07557 c0r c1i - 1.69557 c0i^2 c0r c1i + 
 0.126205 c0i c0r^2 c1i - 1.69557 c0r^3 c1i + 7.66189 c1i^2 - 
 0.763494 c0i^2 c1i^2 + 1.0748 c0i c0r c1i^2 - 7.94349 c0r^2 c1i^2 + 
 0.458615 c0i c1i^3 - 6.16151 c0r c1i^3 - 1.31455 c1i^4 - 
 2.07557 c0i c1r + 1.69557 c0i^3 c1r - 0.433493 c0r c1r + 
 0.126205 c0i^2 c0r c1r + 1.69557 c0i c0r^2 c1r + 
 0.126205 c0r^3 c1r - 1.0748 c0i^2 c1i c1r + 14.36 c0i c0r c1i c1r + 
 1.0748 c0r^2 c1i c1r + 6.16151 c0i c1i^2 c1r + 
 0.458615 c0r c1i^2 c1r + 7.66189 c1r^2 - 7.94349 c0i^2 c1r^2 - 
 1.0748 c0i c0r c1r^2 - 0.763494 c0r^2 c1r^2 + 
 0.458615 c0i c1i c1r^2 - 6.16151 c0r c1i c1r^2 - 
 2.6291 c1i^2 c1r^2 + 6.16151 c0i c1r^3 + 0.458615 c0r c1r^3 - 
 1.31455 c1r^4
```

It gave me a real solution.

But then I thought maybe I should do it in the proper way: use Lagrange multiplier method, take derivatives with respect to each parameters, solve the equations and then find the solution that has the global minimum:

```
    eqs = pol1[1.9, 0.1] + \[Mu]*(c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 - 1)
eq1 = N[D[eqs, c0r]];
eq2 = N[D[eqs, c0i]];
eq3 = N[D[eqs, c1r]];
eq4 = N[D[eqs, c1i]];
eq5 = N[D[eqs, \[Mu]]];

NSolve[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0 && eq3 == 0 && eq4 == 0 && eq5 == 0, {c0r,
   c0i, c1r, c1i, \[Mu]}]
```

Now this second method doesn't even return a real solution set. Where is the mistake?

I will be grateful if you help.

Mathematica version 11.01.0

Comment: Please provide the definition of `pol1[...]`

Comment: I get real solutions.

Comment: So you got real solutions for the NSolve case right? When you plug them into the original equation do you get 1.97153? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: (1) Use @ sign in front of name to notify when you comment. (2) Yes I think I got something like that for one solution. Another gave a smaller value, which I could replicate with `NMinimize` and `Method->"DifferentialEvolution".

Comment: Re 1.97, sometimes exact solvers, such as `Minimize`, have trouble with approximate numbers (floats) -- and you've only given 6 of the 16 digits of each coefficient, although those rounding errors do not seem numerically significant here.  You can improve the result converting them to arbitrary precision numbers: `Minimize[SetPrecision[poly, 16], c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 == 1, {c0r, c0i, c1r, c1i}]` yields `1.55` (in V11.3). [Aside from giving the exact polynomial you used, it would be considerate to others to indicate in the question why you ask about 1.97153.]

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get the answer 1.97153

Comment: @MichaelE2 But when I use the method differential evolution I get your result.

Answer (score 1):

You only need NMinimize to solve your problem!

```
J=2.23232 c0i^2 - 0.0995481 c0i^4 + 2.23232 c0r^2 - 
0.199096 c0i^2 c0r^2 - 0.0995481 c0r^4 - 0.433493 c0i c1i + 
0.126205 c0i^3 c1i + 2.07557 c0r c1i - 1.69557 c0i^2 c0r c1i + 
0.126205 c0i c0r^2 c1i - 1.69557 c0r^3 c1i + 7.66189 c1i^2 - 
0.763494 c0i^2 c1i^2 + 1.0748 c0i c0r c1i^2 - 7.94349 c0r^2 c1i^2 + 
0.458615 c0i c1i^3 - 6.16151 c0r c1i^3 - 1.31455 c1i^4 - 
2.07557 c0i c1r + 1.69557 c0i^3 c1r - 0.433493 c0r c1r + 
0.126205 c0i^2 c0r c1r + 1.69557 c0i c0r^2 c1r + 
0.126205 c0r^3 c1r - 1.0748 c0i^2 c1i c1r + 14.36 c0i c0r c1i c1r + 
1.0748 c0r^2 c1i c1r + 6.16151 c0i c1i^2 c1r + 
0.458615 c0r c1i^2 c1r + 7.66189 c1r^2 - 7.94349 c0i^2 c1r^2 - 
1.0748 c0i c0r c1r^2 - 0.763494 c0r^2 c1r^2 + 
0.458615 c0i c1i c1r^2 - 6.16151 c0r c1i c1r^2 - 
2.6291 c1i^2 c1r^2 + 6.16151 c0i c1r^3 + 0.458615 c0r c1r^3 -1.31455 c1r^4

sol=NMinimize[J, c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 == 1, {c0r, c0i, c1r, c1i}]
(*{1.97153, {c0r -> 0.948685, c0i -> -0.118812, c1r -> 0.00523234,c1i -> -0.293008}}*)
```

NSolve doesn't find a solution!

```
eqn = Map[# == 0 &, D[J, {{c0i, c0r, c1i, c1r}}]];
NSolve[ Join[eqn , {c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 == 1}], {c0i, c0r,c1i, c1r}, Reals]
(*{}*)
```

Comment: Yes I did but why the other method is not working? That is confusing me. It is the proper mathematical method.

Comment: Thank you very much with the effort but there wasn't supposed to be a difference, if there is then there is a problem with Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see Lagrangeparameter...

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, just showing we can solve the system in question.

```
poly = 2.23232 c0i^2 - 0.0995481 c0i^4 + 2.23232 c0r^2 - 
   0.199096 c0i^2 c0r^2 - 0.0995481 c0r^4 - 0.433493 c0i c1i + 
   0.126205 c0i^3 c1i + 2.07557 c0r c1i - 1.69557 c0i^2 c0r c1i + 
   0.126205 c0i c0r^2 c1i - 1.69557 c0r^3 c1i + 7.66189 c1i^2 - 
   0.763494 c0i^2 c1i^2 + 1.0748 c0i c0r c1i^2 - 
   7.94349 c0r^2 c1i^2 + 0.458615 c0i c1i^3 - 6.16151 c0r c1i^3 - 
   1.31455 c1i^4 - 2.07557 c0i c1r + 1.69557 c0i^3 c1r - 
   0.433493 c0r c1r + 0.126205 c0i^2 c0r c1r + 
   1.69557 c0i c0r^2 c1r + 0.126205 c0r^3 c1r - 
   1.0748 c0i^2 c1i c1r + 14.36 c0i c0r c1i c1r + 
   1.0748 c0r^2 c1i c1r + 6.16151 c0i c1i^2 c1r + 
   0.458615 c0r c1i^2 c1r + 7.66189 c1r^2 - 7.94349 c0i^2 c1r^2 - 
   1.0748 c0i c0r c1r^2 - 0.763494 c0r^2 c1r^2 + 
   0.458615 c0i c1i c1r^2 - 6.16151 c0r c1i c1r^2 - 
   2.6291 c1i^2 c1r^2 + 6.16151 c0i c1r^3 + 0.458615 c0r c1r^3 - 
   1.31455 c1r^4;

vars = Variables[poly];
lagrangian = poly + mu*(vars.vars - 1);
derivs = Grad[lagrangian, Variables[lagrangian]];

solns = NSolve[derivs];
realsolns = Select[solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &];
```

Check we made the sum of squares vanish.

```
In[303]:= (vars.vars - 1) /. realsolns

(* Out[303]= {-1.11022302463*10^-16, 7.77156117238*10^-16, 
 6.66133814775*10^-16, -1.11022302463*10^-16, 0., \
-6.10622663544*10^-16, -2.38524477947*10^-16, -1.82145964978*10^-16, \
-6.39245600897*10^-16, 
 2.08166817117*10^-15, -1.2490009027*10^-16, -2.00811589579*10^-14, \
-1.89015469942*10^-14, -3.88578058619*10^-16, 0., 1.38777878078*10^-16} *)
```

Check resulting polynomial values.

```
In[304]:= poly /. realsolns

(* Out[304]= {6.70664718833, 6.70664718833, 6.70664718833, \
6.70664718833, 1.55255414283, 1.55255414283, 2.14374447723, \
2.14374447723, 2.14374443673, 1.9715274388, 1.9715274388, \
1.9715274388, 1.9715274388, 1.97152732129, 1.97152732129, \
1.97152732129} *)
```

We can get that smallest value using optimization directly.

```
{min, vals} = 
 Minimize[pol1, 
  c0r^2 + c0i^2 + c1r^2 + c1i^2 == 1, {c0r, c0i, c1r, c1i}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(* Out[305]= {1.55255311155, {c0r -> 0.13967123044, 
  c0i -> 0.781692557246, c1r -> -0.602194200876, 
  c1i -> 0.0825305977305}} *)
```

So what is different? Just the version. For `NSolve` some of the version 10 releases had trouble getting explicitly real values. Use of `Chop` at some modest level might suffice to recover reasonable results.

Comment: By the way I wrote it in another comment but when I solve it I get 1.97... but then I used the the method Differential evolution and I get your result.